# pine script : can't use variable as defval of input?

Tags: pine-script

I want to use different default value to start base on different ticker

my code:

```
bars1=iff(myticker=='HSI1!',313,iff(myticker=='YM1!',460,999))
lower_tf = input(bars1, title='Lower Timeframe to Assess')
```

it gives error:
Syntax error: Arguments of input function must be of constant type, or 'source' builtin variables; 'defval' is none of them.

how can I use variable as defval of inputs?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can't